# Can I find similar named files ignoring case, dashes, spaces or other characters?

Tags: bash

EDIT 2:

lets say I have 2 directories one contains:

```
/dir1/Test File Name.txt
/dir1/This is anotherfile.txt
/dir1/And-Another File.txt
```

Directory 2 looks like:

```
/dir2/test-File_Name.txt
/dir2/test file_Name.txt
/dir2/This Is another file.txt
/dir2/And another_file.txt
```

How can I find (or match) files that are named similar, in this example file 1 from dir1  would match with file 1 and 2 on dir2 and so on

Trying to do this in bash. Say I have a file named "Test File 1.txt" I want to find any file that is named similar like:

```
test-file 1.txt
test file 1.txt
Test-file-1.txt
test-file_1.zip
```

etc etc

I can ignore case with `find ./files/ -maxdepth 1 -iname $FILE` but don't know how to ignore all the other characters.

Is there a way I can do this in bash?

EDIT:

Sorry, I forgot to mention that I need to iterate on all files, the file name is not always the same, I just used an example.

so it could be named "Test File 1.txt" or it could also be named something completely different "Something Else.txt"

So I want to look for all similar named files using a complete file name as base, but this file name can be different, hope I make more sense.

Comment: `find ./files/ -maxdepth 1 -iname "test?file?1.*"`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin that could probably work, but if I have a lot of files I would need to do it one by one, so I would need to "cut" the file name first?

the name I gave is just an example, I want to look for all files that are similar to a certain file name.

Comment: You can also use regular expressions, `find . -type f -iname "test?file?[0-9].*"` (which can be tailored to anything required)

Comment: maybe it will be easier if you write the use case simple input and output you trying to achieve

Comment: @NaorTedgi thanks, I just did that on Edit 2

Comment: Is a file called `Sour Milk` considered similar to one called `Milk - Sour` ? What about `Sour Milk` and `Soured Milk`? What about `Sour Milk` and `Sour Mikl` ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell in my case, no, only files that have the same words, just casing or spaces or other characters might differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Perl` is your option, please try the following:

```
perl -e '
@files1 = glob "dir1/*";
@files2 = glob "dir2/*";

foreach (@files2) {
    $f2 = $_;
    s#.*/##;                # remove directory name
#   s#\..*?$##;             # remove extension (wrong)
    s#\.[^.]*$##;           # remove extension (corrected)
    s#[\W_]#[\\W_]?#g;      # replace non-alphanumric chars
    $pat = $_ . "\\.\\w+\$";
#   print $pat, "\n";       # uncomment to see the regex pattern
    foreach $f1 (@files1) {
        if ($f1 =~ m#/$pat#i) {
            print "$f1 <=> $f2\n";
        }
    }
}'
```

Output:

```
dir1/And-Another File.txt <=> dir2/And another_file.txt
dir1/Test File Name.txt <=> dir2/test file_Name.txt
dir1/Test File Name.txt <=> dir2/test-File_Name.txt
dir1/This is anotherfile.txt <=> dir2/This Is another file.txt
```

[Explanations]

The concept is to generate a regex pattern on the fly from a filename
in one directory and match it with the files in the other directory.

- File extension is replaced with a pattern which matches it.
- Non-alphanumeric character and underscore are replaced with a pattern
  which matches them including the case the character is missing so that
  `anotherfile` and `another file` match.
- `i` option added to the pattern enables case-insensitive match.
- You can see the generated regex by uncommenting the noted line.

The possible problem is we can not generate a pattern which matches with
`another file` from the filename `anotherfile`. In other words, the
matching is one-directional. A possible workaround is to neglect non-alphanumeric characters and underscores at all in matching. It may result in unexpected overmatching depending on the word and punctuation. We will need to specifically define the `similarity` to step further.

**[Edit]**

In order to get the result back to bash variables, please try:

```
while read -r -d "" line; do
    # do something with the bash variable "line"
    echo "$line"
done < <(

perl -e '
@files1 = glob "dir1/*";
@files2 = glob "dir2/*";

foreach (@files2) {
    $f2 = $_;
    s#.*/##;                # remove directory name
#   s#\..*?$##;             # remove extension (wrong)
    s#\.[^.]*$##;           # remove extension (corrected)
    s#[\W_]#[\\W_]?#g;      # replace non-alphanumric chars
    $pat = $_ . "\\.\\w+\$";
#   print $pat, "\n";       # uncomment to see the regex pattern
    foreach $f1 (@files1) {
        if ($f1 =~ m#/$pat#i) {
            push(@result, "$f1 <=> $f2");
            # if you want just the list of filenames, comment out the line above
            # and uncomment the line below
            #push(@result, $f1, $f2);
        }
    }
}
print join("\0", @result) . "\0";
')
```

The results is stored in the bash variable `line` in line by line.
If you want to tweak the output format, please modify the line `push(@result, ...)`.

**[EDIT]**

Modified to work with the following filename pairs:

- "Sample Filename.txt" <=> "Sample Filename (100).txt"
- "Sample.Filename.txt" <=> "Sample Filename.txt"

Here's the updated code:

```
while read -r -d "" line; do
    # do something with the bash variable "line"
    echo $line
done < <(

perl -e '
@files1 = glob "dir1/*";
@files2 = glob "dir2/*";

foreach (@files2) {
    $f2 = $_;
    s#.*/##;                # remove directory name
    s#\.[^.]*$##;           # remove extension
    s#\s*\(.*?\)##;         # remove parenthesis if any
    s#\s*\[.*?\]##;         # remove square bracket if any
    s#[\W_]#[\\W_]?#g;      # replace non-alphanumric chars
    $pat = $_ . "\\s?((\\(.*?\\))|(\\[.*?\\]))?" . "\\.\\w+\$";
    #print $pat . "\n";     # uncomment to see the regex pattern
    foreach $f1 (@files1) {
        if ($f1 =~ m#/$pat#i) {
            push(@result, "$f1 <=> $f2");
            # if you want just the list of filenames, comment out the line above
            # and uncomment the line below
            #push(@result, $f1, $f2);
        }
    }
}
print join("\0", @result) . "\0";
')
```

Comment: This seems to work for me and its very fast! is it possible to have a message somewhere if there are no file matches for the file currently being tested?

Comment: Also,  this does not recursively test all files in subfolders under dir1, which is fine (but it would be cool to know) because to implement this in a bash script, I would do the loop in bash then pass each file to perl, which tests it against the files in dir2 but how do I get the result back to bash as a variable?

Comment: I think it got it to work exactly as I needed it :) https://pastebin.com/JRmgKBKd not sure if its the best solution, but it works for me.

Altho your awnser was not fully in bash I will accept it as it helped me a lot! thanks!

Comment: Good to hear it's working. I have updated my answer with the version to assign bash variable to the output. BR.

Comment: Answering your previous question, the line `@files1 = glob "dir1/*"` is
equivalent to the type glob `"dir1/*"` in bash. It does not traverse
the directory tree recursively unless we specify so.

Comment: Thanks, I ran into another small problem. if the filename has a dot anywhere it will not find any matches

```this is a file.txt``` will work but ```this.is a file.txt``` will not, because it gets cutoff when it removes the extension, any suggestions?

Comment: Oops! I'm sorry, it's a bug. I've corrected my answer. Thank you for pointing and sorry for bothering you!

Comment: Hey @tshiono thanks for this I've been using it for a while and it has worked perfectly for what I want but I now have another problem, and hopefully you can help me figure it out.

some of the files could be named like 

`Sample Filename.txt   
Sample Filename (100).txt `
this 2 files would not match, is there a way to remove or ignore the text between () or [] in both folders so that it only matches the text that is not inside those?

Comment: oopps I forgot, but also files named like `Sample.Filename.txt` will not match `Sample Filename.txt`

Comment: I'm sorry for my late response. I've updated my answer according to your requirements. I hope they will work. BR.

Comment: don't worry for the late response, I am grateful for your help! THANK YOU!

Comment: Thanks for your patience.
Note that I've added a small modification in the regex pattern such as
`s#\s+\(.*?\)##;` into `s#\s*\(.*?\)##;` considering the case there is
no whitespaces in front of left bracket. Please download the script again. BR.